# Route53 - DNS resolution to a specific port on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have a website that I have hosted on an EC2 instance that runs on port 3000. (e.g. `3.27.83.19:3000` - assuming the IP address of the EC2 instance is `3.27.83.19`)

I have a domain that I have already bought `mydomain.com` through AWS that I already see in Hosted Zones.

How can I set-up Route53 so that when someone hits "mydomain.com", it takes them to `3.27.83.19:3000` rather than `3.27.83.19`

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you don't move the service port to 80? That is the service port for HTTP and would solve your requirement without any redirection. Also there is no way to specify ports in DNS. You would need to implement a redirect in ngnix from port 3000 to port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### point domain to instance ip

To point `example.com` to `3.27.83.19` you simply need to create an `A` record in route53

#### point domain to load balancer

To access the website running port 3000 on an EC2 instance through https://example.com, you need a service that accepts traffic on https://example.com and then forward the traffic to the EC2 instance on port `3000`. You can easily do it with an AWS application load balancer. I like this approach.

There are many benefits using an application load balancer. The important one is that you can configure the SSL certificate easily. The application load balancer also supports host based routing which allows you to host multiple websites.

If you are looking for less expensive solutions, you can also go for setting up an nginx proxy inside the ec2 instance. I personally don't like this approach because you will need to configure SSL at the application level.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: *"then redirect the traffic to 3.27.83.19:3000"* should probably say *"then forward the traffic to the EC2 instance on port 3000"* -- balancers in the use case you describe don't redirect, they forward... and not to a public IP but to the instance target, on its private IP, which does not need to be provided in balancer configuration because the balancer can find the instance by ID.